# How a scheduler is scheduled?

Tags: operating-systems, scheduled-tasks, cpu-usage, scheduling

A scheduler being a system program must be scheduled for execution so that it can wake up and schedule other programs. I read about process scheduling and algorithms but couldn't figure out how a scheduler itself is scheduled.
Does it schedule itself ? if yes then how ? and what algorithm ? because it should be waking up more often than any other program so there must be a different algorithm I think.

I have a *LOT* many similar questions in mind but all of them relate to just one thing, *How a scheduler itself is scheduled ?*

Comment: just to clarify, you are only really speaking of multi-thread/process scheduling, not task schedulers like cron, at, or the the windows task scheduler, right?

Comment: @Frank, yes, In speaking of multi thread/process scheduling.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple approaches to that problem.

### Cooperative Multitasking Schedulers

A cooperative scheduler is invoked every time a program invokes it or *yields* control to it. It *cooperates* with the operating system and other running programs. A program that never yields, e. g. a “hanging” process, will never leave the running state on a machine with a single CPU.

### Preemptive Multitasking scheduler

A very simple preemptive scheduler is invoked periodically by a timed CPU interrupt. A program cannot prevent this (without system level privileges) and will leave the running state because the CPU repositions the instruction pointer during interrupts.

I suggest you read the [Wikipedia article on multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking).